# Postgresql full text search, treat natural number "01" as "1"

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Ex: I have a record in database: `[Example] Attena Illusive - 01 [720p].mkv`
Tried to search with the query:

```sql
 SELECT ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', name), query, 1) as rank, *
      FROM tables, plainto_tsquery('Attena Illusive 1') query
      WHERE to_tsvector('english', name) @@ query
      ORDER BY rank desc
```

But it doesn't return the record. Are we have any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that I can think of is to create a custom [synonym dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY) that maps `01` to `1` and so on.

Then you can create  a *text search configuration* that uses that additional dictionary.

Comment: The extension dict_int does not do what he want, might server as a good example.